# la tabla de BD en postgresql no se actualiza

Tags: php, postgresql, pgadmin

Buen día, estoy practicando con PHP y postgresql para realizar  un proyecto para la universidad y llevo dos días sin poder actualizar una tabla en la BD. He estado cambiando la sintaxis leyendo soluciones en distintos foros y ya no se que pueda ser :(, ya tengo todo lo necesario para empezar a desarrollar pero mientras no pueda actualizar la BD no puedo empezar el proyecto . Agradezco su ayuda.

SO: Ubuntu 16.04

```html
<form action="agregar.php" method="post">
 <p>nombre del switch: <input type="text" name="nombre" /></p>
 <p>puerto: <input type="text" name="puerto" /></p>
 <p>vlan:<input type="vlan" /></p>
 <input type="submit" name="insertar" value="insertar">
</form
```

archivo agregar

```html
<?php

include('conexion.php');

 $nombre=pg_escape_literal($_POST['nombre']);
 $puerto=pg_escape_literal($_POST['puerto']);
 $vlan=pg_escape_literal($_POST['vlan']);

 $query= "INSERT INTO switches (nombre, puerto, vlan) VALUES ('$nombre', '$puerto', '$vlan' )";
 $res = pg_query($query);

?>
```

conexión a la BD

```html
<?php

$dbconn= pg_connect("host=localhost  dbname=centro_de_datos user=postgres password=admin")
 or die ('No se puede conectar a la BD'. pg_last_error());
 ?>
```

Comment: "Deberias evitar la necesidad de 'escapar' valores en SQL. Es desprolijo, proclive a errores y depende de cada base de datos". Usa PreparedStatements siempre. http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Injection-Attacks.html

Answer (score 1):

## escapar

Cuando se escapa el literal ya incluye las comillas de afuera, por lo tanto no hay que ponerlas.

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');

    $nombre=pg_escape_literal($_POST['nombre']);
    $puerto=pg_escape_literal($_POST['puerto']);
    $vlan=pg_escape_literal($_POST['vlan']);

    $query= "INSERT INTO switches (nombre, puerto, vlan) VALUES ($nombre, $puerto, $vlan)";
    $res = pg_query($query);

?>
```

Se puede ver un ejemplo en el manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-escape-literal.php

## verificar SQL

Cuando tengas dudas lo mejor es guardarse la sentencia *SQL* para luego verificarla (o pegarla en la consola de la base de datos para ver por qué falla). Alcanza con poner un `file_put_contents` antes de hacer el `pg_query`:

```
file_put_contents('sql_generado.sql', $query);
```

## verificar el error

Se debe usar `pg_last_error()` para verificar cuál fue el error. Eso se puede mandar al cliente (con un `echo` por ejemplo) o guardarlo en el servidor (con `file_put_contenst('ultimo_error_sql.txt', pg_last_error())`

## pasar los parámetros en forma segura:

usando `pg_query_params` se pueden pasar los parámetros en un arreglo (sin necesidad de escaparlos) en forma segura.

## ojo con los acentos

Cuando te ande esto verifica que funcione bien guardar palabras con acentos y eñes. Si tienes dificultades luego con eso puedes hacer otra pregunta y lo vemos especialmente.